# Finding cell range and appending specific cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, append

What I am trying to do is get values from a sheet and appending to another BUT I will only append values on a condition of finding only numbers in a specific column range and if found I will append the values around it, like so:

```
function saveData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  const pricingWS = sheets[1]
  const takeoffWS = sheets[2]

  var dataRange = pricingWS.getRange(1,4,45,1).getValues()  

  var dataArray = []

  debugger

  for (var i = 1; i <= dataRange.length; i++)
  {
    if(dataRange[i - 1]<=0|| /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(dataRange[i - 1])){
      continue
    }
    else{ 
      dataArray.push(pricingWS.getRange("A7").getValue())
      dataArray.push(pricingWS.getRange(i, 1).getValue())
      dataArray.push(pricingWS.getRange(i, 2).getValue())
      dataArray.push(pricingWS.getRange(i, 4).getValue())
      dataArray.push(pricingWS.getRange("A8").getValue())
      takeoffWS.appendRow(dataArray)
      dataArray = []
    }   
    
  }
  
}
```

Just to add more context this is the sheet I am getting the values from:
[sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxSm0.png)

This is the result sheet:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVHrO.png)

I am not sure if this code is the best approach to it. I am googling everything and coding it step by step. lol.

BUT, that even isn't my actual problem.

My problem is with the first and last push, I want to find a way to read the cell location I am in while doing the for loop and if it is out of the range I want, I want it to to change the getRange value of the first and last push.

To better explain, in the result sheet image above, my first and last column are repeating themselves because I hard coded them in my push. But what I want is when the var i of my dataRange is in the range D10:D15 I want it to push A7 and A8, when it gets to the range D40:D45 I want it to push A36 and A38 and so on.

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In your question, `Just to add more context this is the sheet I am getting the values from:` and `This is the result sheet:` are the sample input and output situations you expect? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the detailed logic for achieving your expected result?

Comment: No need to apologize!
English is not my first language as well, so all good! =D

Yeah, both images are my input and output as you said.
but now, what I want is to be able to identify the range my function is getting the values from. For example:
if the range that the for loop is in between cell 10 and 20 I want it to push the cell A7
else if my range that the for loop is in between cell 40 and 50 I want it to push the cell A8. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function saveData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  const shts = ss.getSheets();
  const sh1 = shts[1]
  const sh2 = shts[2]
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange(1, 4, 45, 1).getValues().flat()
  vs1.forEach((e, i) => {
    if (!isNaN(e)) {
      let dA = [];
      dA.push(sh1.getRange("A7").getValue())
      dA.push(sh1.getRange(i + 1, 1).getValue())
      dA.push(sh1.getRange(i + 1, 2).getValue())
      dA.push(sh1.getRange(i + 1, 4).getValue())
      dA.push(sh1.getRange("A8").getValue())
      sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, dA.length).setValues([dA]);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: First, thank you for replaying and helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Second, could explain to me why did you use .flat() and also a little bit more about the code? I am asking that because I see that you used a lambda expression and I am not sure how to use it. I wanna learn. lol

Comment: It did bring the code but it kept repeating itself and that is why I was "flushing" the array every loop.
I worked a way around of what I needed and this is my code now:

Comment: I don't understand your last two comments.  What is the lambda expression you are talking about?

Comment: the first comment I just want to know more why did you use foreach instead of for, lambda and the last line of code. to explain better about your code so I can understand why did you do what you did.

Comment: the second comment, look at my second answer below.

Comment: I just decided to change the code by inittializing the array inside the loop

Comment: If it doesn't require a break out of a loop then I always use array methods.  They're easier to write, take up less space and work well with other chained methods. You can do more and write less.

Comment: ok, nice!! got it!! I will post the result of you code once the stack overflow let me.